# Pydantic with AsyncAttrs SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I want to use AsyncAttrs of SQLAlchemy with Pydantic .from_obj method

I have a simple SQLAlchemy Model, with inherited AsyncAttrs as said in sqlalchemy doc:
[AsyncAttrs doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession)

```
class ModelBase(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    ...
```

```
class A(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    bs = relationship()
```

and pydantic schemas:

```
class BsRelationSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


    
class ASchema(BaseModel):
    bs: BsRelationSchema
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I can create instance of schema in this way:

```
a = (await session.scalars(select(A))).one()
a_schema = ASchema(bs=await a.awaitable_attrs.bs)
```

But how can i do this?

```
a = (await session.scalars(select(A))).one()
a_schema = ASchema.from_obj(a1)
```

Comment: @python_user sorry, i mean .from_orm method. 
Exactly the same, as in
`a_schema = ASchema(bs=await a.awaitable_attrs.bs)` -
load pydantic schema from sqlalchemy model obj

Comment: do you have any update or solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing something similar lately, and there are two methods that I've used so far. It touches upon some of the things mentioned by DurandA, but a little less complex. The methods described below are taken from [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession)

(Please also note I'll be using the new model_validate instead of from_orm, as described in [Pydantic migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#changes-to-pydanticbasemodel), but it works the same with `from_orm`, just trying to avoid the deprecated method.)

Anyway, method 1: after you get  each object, you do an await on their awaitable_attrs before creating the schema. Yes, I am aware that is what you posted, I just wanted to write it here for completeness.

```py
a = (await session.scalars(select(A))).one()
await a.awaitable_attrs.bs
a_schema = ASchema.model_validate(a)
```

Method 2: using the [selectinload](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.selectinload) eager loader. You can modify your query to:

```py
a = (await session.scalars(select(A).options(selectinload(A.bs)))).one()
a_schema = ASchema.model_validate(a)
```

Hope this helps!

Update: please be aware that this is just one way of relationship loading styles and they correspond to different SQL queries. Please have a look at [Relationship Loading Techniques](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude implementation of loading all relationships defined in the pydantic model using `awaitable_attrs` recursively according the SQLAlchemy schema:

```py
from typing import Any, List, Type, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import RelationshipProperty
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)

async def load_relationships_and_create_pydantic(
    db_obj, 
    pydantic_model: Type[T], 
    session: AsyncSession
) -> T:
    # create a dictionary to hold the attributes including relationships
    loaded_attrs = {}

    for field_name, field_info in pydantic_model.__annotations__.items():
        mapper_attrs = inspect(db_obj.__class__).mapper.attrs
        # check if the field is a relationship that should be loaded
        if field_name in mapper_attrs and isinstance(mapper_attrs[field_name], RelationshipProperty):
            relationship_data = await getattr(db_obj.awaitable_attrs, field_name)
            if isinstance(relationship_data, list): # relationship is a list of items, use type of the list
                loaded_attrs[field_name] = [
                    await load_relationships_and_create_pydantic(item, field_info.__args__[0], session)
                    for item in relationship_data
                ]
            else: # relationship is a single item
                loaded_attrs[field_name] = await load_relationships_and_create_pydantic(relationship_data, field_info, session)
        else:
            # regular attribute, get its value
            attr_value = getattr(db_obj, field_name, None)
            if attr_value is not None:
                loaded_attrs[field_name] = attr_value

    # create the Pydantic instance
    return pydantic_model(**loaded_attrs)
```

See [this runnable example](https://gist.github.com/DurandA/202c1b15b2d3bd2a7f3c9f5e6af8c677)

From your example, you would use it as follows:

```py
a = (await session.scalars(select(A))).one()
a_schema = awaitload_relationships_and_create_pydantic(a, ASchema)
```

Note that this is not well tested and I did not investigate on the [performance implications of using `awaitable_attrs`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs). If there is no heavy penalty, I hope something similar will be added to the [next version of SQLModel](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/654). Also see this [interesting related SQLAlchemy discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9731).