# Performance implications of using AsyncAttrs/awaitable_attrs in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, pydantic, sqlmodel, greenlets

I am using SQLAlchemy with an async driver. I am investigating on the possibility to [load related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77456457/1584915) using [`AsyncAttrs`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncAttrs)/[`awaitable_attrs`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs) according to Pydantic/[SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) models.

What are exactly the performance implications of using `awaitable_attrs` to load relationships? The [documentation on that matter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncAttrs) confuses me:

> The AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs performs a call against the attribute that is approximately equivalent to using the AsyncSession.run_sync() method, e.g.:
>
> ```py
> for b1 in await async_session.run_sync(lambda sess: a1.bs):
>     print(b1)
> ```

Moreover, the documentation on [`AsyncSession.run_sync()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncConnection.run_sync) states:

> The provided callable is invoked inline within the asyncio event loop, and will block on traditional IO calls. IO within this callable should only call into SQLAlchemy’s asyncio database APIs which will be properly adapted to the greenlet context.

It is clear that loading an unloaded relationship emits I/O to the database, but is it blocking the event loop while doing so? Additionally, are relationships that are already loaded (through eager loading) queried again?

Comment: `run_sync` will **not** block IO calls from callables that are from SQLAlchemy, if you were to pass it a "non SQLAlchemy" callable, then that call would block. IOW, pass only SQLAlchemy things to `run_sync` and it won't block your loop, SQLAlchemy knows how to handle this in a non blocking manner. The second part "are relationships that are already loaded (through eager loading) queried again?" you can confirm this yourself by turning on `echo=True` in the engine